# Writing String to file in bold and underlined style

Tags: java, ms-word

I have class `WriteFile` which has method `WriteToFile` which writes `String` to word document.

```
  WriteFile data=new WriteFile("C:/test3.doc",true);  
  data.writeToFile(user.saxeli+" "+user.gvari+" "+user.asaki+" "+user.swori);
```

How to write `String` to "test3.doc" in bold and underlined style?

Here is the WriteFile class:

```
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class WriteFile {

 private String path;
 private boolean append=true;
 public WriteFile(String path,boolean append){
  this.path=path; this.append=append;
}
 public void writeToFile(String text) throws IOException{
  FileWriter write=new FileWriter(path,append);
  PrintWriter print_line= new PrintWriter(write);
  print_line.printf("%s"+"%n", text);
  print_line.close();
}
}
```

Comment: *"which writes String to word document."*  I very much doubt that it **actually** a Word Doc. as opposed to something that MS Word is willing to *pretend is a Word Doc.*

Comment: Well how exactly does your `WriteFile` create a Word document? Obviously a plain text file can't contain style information...

Comment: I think you need to script your way into writing the doc file http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2006/02/01/how-can-i-boldface-a-specific-word-throughout-a-microsoft-word-document.aspx?Redirected=true

Comment: Are you using Apache POI or some other library to create the document? What does the `writeToFile` function look like? We'll need more information to answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may refer this ::

```
 XWPFParagraph paragraphOne = document.createParagraph();
        XWPFRun paragraphOneRunOne = paragraphOne.createRun();
        paragraphOneRunOne.setItalic(true);
        paragraphOneRunOne.setText(text);
```

follow this link ::
http://tkgospodinov.com/writing-microsoft-word-documents-in-java-with-apache-poi/

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/hwpf/). That library has the possibility to write to a microsoft word file and use bold and underlined (font) styles.