# How to write text with spans from EditText to .txt?

Tags: android, android-edittext, spannablestring

I want selectable text to be bold. I did it using Spans.

But there is a problem that I can not write this text with spans to .txt

```
 SpannableString string = new SpannableString(selectedText);
 string.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), 0, selectedText.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
 mEditText.setText(mEditText.getText().replace(startSelection, endSelection, string, 0, string.length()));
```

Comment: A plain .txt file does not contain any formatting info. Maybe you want an .rtf file?

Comment: You can not do with `SpannableString`  . You need to look for way with `JAVA IO`. Try [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20326171/writing-string-to-file-in-bold-and-underlined-style) or similar .

Comment: You mentioned that there is a problem, but did not describe the problem, or even show any code that would write text to a file (which I assume is what you mean by "write... to .txt".  What is the problem?